# How to remove null date data in Teradata 16.20

Tags: null, teradata

I have a number of rows in which date fields are null.  I need to include these rows in my answer set. The only things we've managed to accomplish is to set a "placeholder date" (01-01-1900) and remove them in Excel. I want Teradata NOT to yield "?"; I want the equivalent of ''.

Here's an exact example:
         , CASE 
            WHEN SOA.Performed_date IS NULL THEN '' 
            ELSE SOA.Performed_date
            END AS Sequence_of_Activities

The only code I've gotten to work is:
         , CASE 
            WHEN SOA.Performed_date IS NULL THEN '0001-01-01'
            ELSE SOA.Performed_date
            END AS Sequence_of_Activities

Here's a similar working example, equally unsatisfying:

```
, Max(CASE WHEN Care_Activity_Type_ID = 435 
        THEN PERFORMED_DATE 
        ELSE DATE '0001-01-01' 
    end) Annl_Reassess
```

The error for the first example is: Datatype mismatch in expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `''` instead of null you must cast the date to a string:

```
coalesce(to_char(Performed_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), '')
```

Btw, the `?` representing NULL is a client setting.

Comment: This works nicely.  

If there's a valid date, it selects it; otherwise, it makes it null.  Lovely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact Teradata RDBMS returns *NULL*, not ?. So you can ensure in RDBMS that not NULL is delivered (as Dieter wrote above using COALESCE).

But in SQL Assistant & TD Studio you can change how *NULL* is displayed (and exported). Maybe you're looking to change this setting. :) 
In TD Studio it's Settings -> Teradata Datatools -> Result Set Viewer -> Data Format -> Display NULL Value as: -> >here you are<